# Notifications for LG WebOS updates and security fixes (e.g. a mailing list)

Tags: security, smart-tv

I have a LG WebOS TV (2021) which has no connection to the internet. Every few months I activate the internet connection in the firewall (OpenWrt) and check if updates are available. A somewhat manual and unfortunate solution.

Is there a mailing list or any other kind of notifications for WebOS release updates and security fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you registered your product ? [Product Registration](https://www.lg.com/us/mylg/product-registration)
Technically, if you have registered it, they should send you an email when there's updates (improvements) to that product - not just recalls.
Now, if you're registered and they are still not sending you updates, you should send them feedback via [Feedback link](https://www.lg.com/us/support/feedback?url=/us/support/contact&omniture=us:support:contact) or email their support and ask for this feature.
Are you worried about leaving the connection open all the time ? That's understandable, I guess...